# Why are nondisjoint union's, complement's, and intersections closed in $\sigma$-algebra?

Tags: measure-theory

It is clear to me that all of these conditions are connected through the equalities:

$$\mu(A\cup B)=\mu(A)+\mu(B)-\mu(A\cap B)$$

$$\mu(A-B)=\mu(A)-\mu(A\cap B)$$

If one of these is measurable then every other should be as well.

My problem is why should we expect that $$A\cap B, A\cup B, A-B$$

are measurable. To a more specific example define $X=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, $A=\{1,3\}$ and $\{1,4\}$. Also define

$$\mu(X)=10$$
$$\mu(A)=4$$
$$\mu(B)=5$$

It is reasonable to me for us to say

$$\mu(\emptyset)=0$$
$$\mu(X-A)=6$$
$$\mu(X-B)=5$$

but past that I don't see why we would make the claim that
$$A\cap B, A\cup B, A-B$$

are measurable.

Comment: Do you know the definition of sigma algebra and a measure?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy This question is more about the heart of what it means to have a sigma-algebra less so about the definition. My question is more about why we would require complements, unions, and intersections to be closed when we can assign sizes to sets without those requirements. The question is better phrased "Yea it is nice to have closure of these properties in a sigma-algebra but what is the consequence if we don't and why is that consequence a bad thing?"

Comment: @user160110: We want to make as many interesting things measurable as possible. As a follow-up, you might ask, "Why not make everything measurable? Why not take $\mu \colon \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow [0, \infty]$?" To this, one might respond, "Because then you run into problems described by, e.g., the [Banach Tarski paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-measurable_set#Consistent_definitions_of_measure_and_probability)."

Comment: We would like a kind of “inclusion-exclusion” to hold: that $\mu(A\cup B) = \mu(A)+\mu(B)-\mu(A\cap B)$. This requires that if $A$ and $B$ are measurable, we also have $A\cap B$ be measurable. More generally, we would like measurable sets to “behave well” with respect to standard set-theoretic operations, which are unions, intersections, and differences. If anything, the slightly more questionable requirement is closure under countable unions....

Answer (score 1):

What does it mean to be a sigma-algebra? We define a sigma-algebra $\Sigma$  on a set $X$ to be a collection of subsets of $X$ which is closed under complements and countable unions, and also includes $X$. From that, it follows that $\emptyset \in \Sigma$. It also gives us closure under countable intersections.

However, based on the conversation in the comments, it seems like you're more curious about why the definitions for sigma-algebras and measures are the way that they are. For that, I'll point you to a quote from Lieb and Loss' *Analysis*:

> If $A_1, A_2, \ldots$ is a sequence of disjoint sets in $\Sigma$, then $$\mu \left( \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_i \right) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(A_i)\hspace{1.5in}(2)$$ The big breakthrough, historically, was the realization that countable additivity is an essential requirement [of a measure]. It is, and was, easy to construct finitely additive measures (i.e., where (2) holds with $\infty$ replaced by an arbitrary finite number), but a satisfactory theory of integration cannot be developed this way $\ldots$[The Lebesgue measure] is translation invariant - meaning that for every fixed $y \in \mathbb{R}^n, \mathcal{L}^n (A) = \mathcal{L}^n (\{x+y : x \in A\})$. Up to an over-all constant, *it is the only translation invariant measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$*. The fact that the classical measure can be extended in a *countably additive way* to a sigma-algebra containing all balls is a triumph which, having been achieved, makes integration theory relatively painless.

In brief, the way measures and sigma-algebras are defined is essential for a robust and interesting theory of integration.